# Content alignment for Gridviewcolumn in the listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

Please see the picture below 
[image]

Following is the code for this ::

```
<Grid>
                <ListView Style="{StaticResource listViewStyle}" Name="transactionListView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="transactionListView_MouseDoubleClick" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource gridViewHeaderColumnStyle}">
                            <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Serial" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Serial}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Seller" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Seller}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Buyer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Buyer}" />
                                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Bales" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Bales}" />
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you want to center to content for all your cells? In that case you can add `HorizontalContentAlignment` for `ListViewItem`

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--...-->
</ListView>
```

Comment: what about only one column? "Date" for example?

Comment: I'm not sure why I cannot replicate this fix in Snoop (there seems to be a `ContentPresenter` some way down nested in the `ListViewItem` whose `HorizontalAlignment` needs to be `Stretch`, but which is not updated in accordance with the `ListViewItem.HorizontalContentAlignment` property when changing that in Snoop - one time binding there?), but at runtime, this works.

Comment: And how to center only several ones?

Comment: This is NOT the answer, as long as this code will align content for all columns, and not for individual columns.