# Setting different alignments for listview columns

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm having trouble drawing a listview with columns that are left or centre aligned. I've looked at a few of solutions that I've found on here or other forums but they either seem to work for [all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883182/content-alignment-for-gridviewcolumn-in-the-listview?rq=1) or I can't get them working.

The best I've got so far is this code, but everything is left aligned (I've put the right-aligns in to test the code). Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

```
<ListView Name="lsvQuestions" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">                
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Width="450" Header="Question Text">
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionText}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Type">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionType}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Page Number">
                     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionPageNumber}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Order">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionOrder}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>               
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your `ListViewItem`s don't stretch the content by default and that's why all items appear on the left. Add this and it will work:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 13):

Although [LPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398263/378115)'s hint had already saved thousands of headaches, I would go even further and define **HorizontalContentAlignment** and **VerticalContentAlignment** to **stretch** in order to target an expected alignment behaviours on most used table driven controls:

- ListView column headers and items templates
- DataGrid column headers and cell templates.

  ```
  <Window x:Class="TaskManager.UI.Views.AcumuladosPorTarefaWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:v="clr-namespace:TaskManager.UI.Views"
  xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"        
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  Title="AcumuladosPorTarefaWindow" Height="451.533" Width="323.305"
  >
  <Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AcumuladosPorTarefa}" SelectedItem="{Binding LinhaSelecionada}">
      <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding TarefaID}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <GridViewColumnHeader>
                      <TextBlock Text="ID" TextAlignment="Center" />
                  </GridViewColumnHeader>
              </GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tarefa.Nome}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="Nome" TextAlignment="Left"/>
              </GridViewColumn>
              <GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding DuracaoInMS}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <GridViewColumnHeader Width="auto">
                      <TextBlock Text="Duração" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                  </GridViewColumnHeader>
              </GridViewColumn>
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AcumuladosPorTarefa}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding LinhaSelecionada}" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="20" CanUserSort="True" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                  <TextBlock Text="ID" TextAlignment="Right" />
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TarefaID}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" MinWidth="150" CanUserSort="True">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="Nome" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tarefa.Nome}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Duração" Width="auto" MinWidth="25" IsReadOnly="True">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="Duração" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding DuracaoInMS}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                  </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
  </Window>
  ```

Rembember: you can always [define your default styles and other resources at application level](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/) so you don't have to define it every view.

Hope it helps someone else like LPL's hint helped me.